# Response from java code and db query are ordered differently?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring-boot, azure-sql-database

I have a spring boot api that fetches data from Azure SQL. I am querying the data using either an id or a reference with a native query using jpa and in the java code I have used String and Long for the id. In the database, the id column is a numeric.

the query:

```
select * from tableName where id=:pId or reference=:pReference;
```

Depending on what data type I use in the code, I get a different order of records in the response but the order is important in my application. When I directly query the database, I get the correct order of records every time.

Why is this happening so I can try to maintain a consistent ordering? In my java code, the user is only allowed to pass either an id or a reference, so either the id or reference will be null in the query.

Comment: If you want results in a specific order, then use `order by ...`

Comment: RDBMS systems don't sort inherently, you have to tell them to.  So yes, either user an ORDER BY in your SQL or sort the results in your app after you receive the data from the API.

Comment: “Give me all the marbles from the bag.” If you want the red ones first, you have to say so. Otherwise, like a bag of marbles, a table is just an unordered bag of rows.

Comment: *"Depending on what data type I use in the code"* if you're using different data types, then the query isn't the same in the RDBMS. `WHERE id = @SomeInt` and `WHERE ID = @SomeString` could be *very* differently processed.

Comment: It sounds like you've discovered that strings are not numeric. Numbers will sort `1, 2, 10` but strings will sort lexicographically `'1', '10', '2'`.